# Spacing in a html table between rows

Tags: html, css, css-tables, tablerow

I'm trying to build a table with the `display: table` attribute.

The problem I'm having is that I've got a structure where my Table contains different rows where each two rows should build a group of rows.
Therefore I used `table-row-group`

```
<div class="table">
<div style="display: table-row-group;">
<div class="display: table-row;">
    <div class="cell">
        <p>18:00:00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell right">
        <p>A</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="display: table-row;">
    <div class="cell team">
        <p>Team 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell center">
        <p>:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell right team">
        <p>Team 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2xqfdn38/

What I want to do now, between each table-row-group should be a space but not between the table-rows. I tried to add a border-spacing to the class table, but this will result in a spacing between all rows and not only between the table-row-groups.

Does anybody knows a solution?

Comment: Why don't you use a real table?

Comment: Please see my answer with a working demo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution is:

```
.table {
    font-size: 18px;
    border-spacing: 0 10px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;/*Set border-collapse: collapse*/
}

.row-group {
    display: table-row-group;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #ffffff;/*Change border color to white and apply only to bottom*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2xqfdn38/9/)

And one better one is to use pseudo-element `after`:

```
.row-group:after{
    content: "";
    height:20px;
    display: block;
}
```

[**fiddle example using after**](http://jsfiddle.net/2xqfdn38/13/)

You can adjust height according your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use border-collapse in table.

i hope it will helps you.

```
border-collapse:collapse;
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/d5ddrc6w/)***

Comment: The code in the DEMO also sets `.row-group { display: table}`, which is crucial for the effect. You should say this in the answer. Making the row groups tables may have a serious effect on other things: you don’t have a single table any more, so you cannot e.g. let browsers allocate column widths according to content requirements (or they may break the tabular layout).

Answer (score 2):

The following changes in your css will add space between row groups.

```
.row-group::after
{
    content: "\00a0";
}
```

I have also updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xqfdn38/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the border spacing from table class, Then use a border the same colour as your page background to create a space between the groups, this css should work fine;

```
.row .cell {
border-bottom: 10px solid #fff; /* FOR A WHITE BACKGROUND */
}
.row.header .cell {
border: none !Important;
}
```

Demo here > http://jsfiddle.net/23of5xv8/